# Reflection tag...keep and add description, or remove?

Tags: discussion, tagging

So, I just  came across a really bad question (that's in the process of getting close votes),  and the only tag was [reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflection), which has no description.  As the relatively new person here,  I don't have much of an opinion on the value of adding a description or nuking it, but I think one of the two should be done.

Comment: I wrote up an excerpt. It's an ambiguous tag (cannot stand on its own) but not the worst of the tags we have.

Comment: I also went through the questions that had only this tag and either edited or voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best to keep it. True, it cannot stand alone, but this shouldn't be an issue *per se*. This is adequately addressed by the new tag excerpt.

What is more important in my opinion is that it is entirely conceivable that someone favourites or ignores the tag. This usually means it has enough merit to be retained. I consider this case no different.